# Can not run vbs with current Folder directory

Tags: vbscript

It is my first vbs experience.
I try to keep my Problem short. 
This one **works**, when I run it with my .bat:

```
Option Explicit
On Error Resume Next
ExcelMacroExample
Sub ExcelMacroExample()
 Dim xlApp 
 Dim xlBook 
 Set xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application") 
 Set xlBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open("C:\.....\RunScript.xlsm", 0, 
 True) 
 xlApp.Run "Auto_Open"
 xlApp.Quit 
 Set xlBook = Nothing 
 Set xlApp = Nothing 
End Sub
```

And this one **works** (shows me my corect current directory with my file):

```
Dim oFSO
Set oFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
sScriptDir = oFSO.GetParentFolderName(WScript.ScriptFullName)
Wscript.Echo sScriptDir & "\RunScript.xlsm"
```

But if I combine them, it does **not work**:

```
Option Explicit
On Error Resume Next
ExcelMacroExample
Sub ExcelMacroExample()
 Dim xlApp 
 Dim xlBook 

 Dim oFSO
 Set oFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
 sScriptDir = oFSO.GetParentFolderName(WScript.ScriptFullName)
 Set fileDirectory = sScriptDir & "\RunScript.xlsm"

 Set xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application") 
 Set xlBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(fileDirectory, 0, 
 True) 
 xlApp.Run "Auto_Open"
 xlApp.Quit 
 Set xlBook = Nothing 
 Set xlApp = Nothing 
End Sub
```

Comment: Don't use `Set` when you're assigning a string to a variable - it's for objects.  Try `fileDirectory = sScriptDir & "\RunScript.xlsm"` instead

Comment: Also, you have `Option Explicit` switched on and haven't declared `fileDirectory` anywhere I can see...  The `On Error Resume Next` will just be hiding that error as well.

Comment: Thank you Dave. How can I declare fileDirectory?
Just: Dim fileDirectory?

Comment: Yes, same as the other variable declarations.

Comment: It works. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Like I said, thank you Dave. That works.
However I found another issue, now with vb**A** inside the **RunScript.xlsm**
This code **works** with the vb**S** before:

```
Sub Auto_Open()

Application.DisplayAlerts = False
ActiveWorkbook.RefreshAll
ActiveWorkbook.Save
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:= _
        "C:\...\MyCSV.csv" _
        , FileFormat:=xlCSV, CreateBackup:=False
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
ThisWorkbook.Saved = True
Application.Quit
End Sub
```

But if I change here the path, it just **works** when I run the **RunScript.xlsm**, but not when I run my **vbS**:

```
Sub Auto_Open()

Application.DisplayAlerts = False
ActiveWorkbook.RefreshAll
ActiveWorkbook.Save

Dim relativePath As String
relativePath = Application.ActiveWorkbook.path & "\MyCSV.csv"

ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=relativePath, FileFormat:=xlCSV, CreateBackup:=False

Application.DisplayAlerts = True
ThisWorkbook.Saved = True
Application.Quit
End Sub
```

I think it is beacause of the ActiveWorkbook, I tried already ThisWorkbook, and I tried it without Application.

Comment: with the "relativePath" vbA the vbS just saving MyCSV.csv at my Documents (C:\Users\MyName\Documents). There should be a workaround because I think the vbS cann not recognise the path in vbA. Maybe I can give it from vbS to vbA using like: (xlApp.Run "Auto_Open(sScriptDir)") or something like that

Comment: A sweet workaround I just created. It works. I added "xlBook.SaveAs sScriptDir & "\MyCSV_toIgnore.csv" to the vbS and now it is recognising my Path inside the vbA and save my "MyCSV.csv" and "MyCSV_toIgnore.csv" in the correct path :)